# How to reference signals outside of models.py

Tags: python, django

In the documentation for `Django`, it specifies that `models.py` is a good place to locate callback functions for signals (`post_save`, `pre_save`, etc).

> Where should this code live?
>
> You can put signal handling and registration code anywhere you like.
>   However, you'll need to make sure that the module it's in gets
>   imported early on so that the signal handling gets registered before
>   any signals need to be sent. This makes your app's models.py a good
>   place to put registration of signal handlers.
>
> source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

However, I have a significant amount of business logic that relies on signals and it's becoming challenging to view them in the same file as all my models.

I would like to move them to another file, but I don't know how or where I can reference them.

So, given the following file structure, could you provide an example of how I can reference a secondary (or tertiary and so on) file that contains appropriate signals?

```
# models.py located in /myapp/some_installed_app/
from django import needed.modules
... # some reference to signals.py?

class SomeModel()
    pass

# signals.py located in /myapp/some_installed_app/
from django import needed.things
...

def somefun(sender,**kwargs)
    pass

post_save.connect(somefun, sender=SomeModel)
```

Comment: `from signals import *` in your `models.py` wouldn't work?

Comment: @favoretti I'll try that now.

Comment: If you are importing signals in your models.py, and models in your signal.py, you may need to use specific import statements to avoid circular imports:  `import signals` and `import models`, as opposed to using `*` or and members of that module.

Comment: Although probably not, considering that it's not fundefs only, but also funcalls.

Comment: Then maybe you could leave fundefs in signals.py and refer to them (the actual `post_save.connect(...)` calls in models.py still.

Comment: `from signals import *` seems to work, however, the server complains that it can't find my models. `NameError: name 'SomeModel' is not defined` ... `from signals import *`

Comment: Thats what I was talking about, with circular imports. Use `import signals`, and `import models` and adjust your references accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you're trying to explain. My question was: `given the following file structure, could you provide an example of how I can reference a secondary (or tertiary and so on) file that contains appropriate signals?` Please do so as an answer.

Comment: how about you reference your model using django's `.get_model()` ? To avoid circular import.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about "connecting" signals in models.py while keeping the functions in signals.py?

---

an example:

```
# models
from myapp import signals
class MyModel(models.Model)
    pass
post_save.connect(signals.do_some_stuff_with_mymodel, sender = MyModel)

# signals
def do_some_stuff_with_mymodel(**kwargs):
    pass
```

that way you don't have to import `models` in `signals` at all

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would have been to import signals in your `__init__.py` file.

This would have ensured early registration and avoided circular imports.