# receive django-allauth signal outside of models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-signals

Have seen this question,

[How to reference signals outside of models.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062951/how-to-reference-signals-outside-of-models-py)

The mentioned question address the django's built in signals (`post_save` etc..), I'm asking about allauth signals, which are emitted by the package,(`user_logged_in` etc..)

the receiver captures the signals when the receiver is placed in `models.py`, I want to use the signal files inside of `signals.py`. How do I capture signals outside of `models.py`?

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print "user signed up!! ;)"
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can register the signals by importing signals.py in the app's **init**.py file like in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062951/how-to-reference-signals-outside-of-models-py)

Hope it will help!